# BPY control what vertex color channel I include in my gltf export

Tags: python, export, gltf, vertex-colors

I would like to export a gltf file using a specific vertex color channel name "Color_Id". Does anyone know how I could make sure this channel is exported while other vertex color channels exist in my blend file?

Comment: Try clicking the little camera next to its name in the Color Attribute panel in the Properties editor. Then export.

Comment: (In bpy, that's setting the `mesh.color_attributes.render_color_index`.)

Comment: Thank you. Is there an official answer that can be posted to mark this as closed?

Comment: @scurest Is it not possible to export multiple vertex color to gltf?

Comment: Try turning on "Attributes".

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm clicking the little camera next too the color attribute panel or using bpy's mesh.color_attributes.render_color_index exports with the desired Vertex color. Thanks to scurest for the information.